# How to get entrypoint defined in docker image to wrap it in helm installation

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm, docker-entrypoint

I use helm3 to deploy into k8s.

Sometimes I need to "wrap" docker entry point for various reasons.
One of them is to fill right environment (envs).

Usually I do it like this:

```
deployment.yaml

...
       image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}"
        command: ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
        args: ["bash", "-c", "my-script.sh && exec /root/entrypoint"]
...
```

It works well, but as you can see there is `root/entrypoint` hardcoded.

Is there a way to have it defined from docker image?

Comment: (Especially in a Kubernetes/Helm context, can you fill in the `env:` of the pod spec using Helm template logic, or importing variables from ConfigMaps?)

Comment: I have them only in runtime. Can't prefill them